# VB.net 2010 RDLC dynamic tablix inside list

Tags: report, grouping, reportviewer, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I have a table(tablix) inside a list in my report, I want to group and list detail items in the tablix, but its not working. When I try to create the grouping in the tablix it says that it needs to have static members. How do I get around that?
Here is a picture to clarify a bit...
[image]

Once I row group the list(red), I get the correct information on all the fields aside from the tablix(blue). In the tablix(blue) I get the aggregates(orange) correct, ot_plt count shows 3 the other sums show the summed total correctly, however; the details(pink) only shows the 1st item and doesn't list all 3 items.

So my question is, what do I have to do to make all detailed items show up on the (pink).
I tried to add another group on the tablix(blue) however, that throws the static member error, i mentioned in the beginning; any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanx....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this question...

But good news is I found the answer and since there were 53 views in this question. I will post the answer.

I created a sub-report inside of the (red) list and placed the (blue)tablix in the subreport. I then grouped the row as I did with (pink) and added 2 parameters to the subreport, passing values(criteria) to it from the main report.

That allowed me to show detail on (blue)tablix.

Hope this helps anyone who is having this issue...